# Why is seaborn objects breaking on basic data?

Tags: python, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am a native R user but need to use Python in a new job. Seaborn objects seems to match up with `ggplot` much more closely (I know about `plotnine`; let's ignore it for now).

Unfortunately, it is not working and I cannot find help on the error. The code below is as basic as it gets, and the example was created using trivially modified code taken directly from [the SO page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html).

In my current position we are using a unified Python environment, so my ability to tweak/change/test is severely limited, if not unavailable.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print("Seaborn version:", sns.__version__)

x_min = 0
x_max = 50
x_len = 25
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, x_len)
y = x ** (np.random.rand(x_len))

temp_d = pd.DataFrame(
    {"x": x, "y": y}
)

print(temp_d.head())

plt.scatter(x, y)
so.Plot(
    data = temp_d, x = "x", y = "y"
).add(so.Dots())
```

I get a "TypeError: data type 'boolean' not understood":

```
    834         # Process the scale spec for coordinate variables and transform their data
...
---> 97             boolean_vector = vector.dtype in boolean_dtypes
     98         else:
     99             boolean_vector = bool(np.isin(vector, [0, 1, np.nan]).all())

TypeError: data type 'boolean' not understood
```

I have attached a picture:

[image]

Full anonymized trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/data/anaconda3/shared/xxxxxxxxxx3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

/data/anaconda3/shared/xxxxxxxxxx3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core/plot.py in _repr_png_(self)
    277     def _repr_png_(self) -> tuple[bytes, dict[str, float]]:
    278 
--> 279         return self.plot()._repr_png_()
    280 
    281     # TODO _repr_svg_?

/data/anaconda3/shared/xxxxxxxxxx3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core/plot.py in plot(self, pyplot)
    819         """
    820         with theme_context(self._theme_with_defaults()):
--> 821             return self._plot(pyplot)
    822 
    823     def _plot(self, pyplot: bool = False) -> Plotter:

/data/anaconda3/shared/xxxxxxxxxx3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core/plot.py in _plot(self, pyplot)
    834         # Process the scale spec for coordinate variables and transform their data
    835         coord_vars = [v for v in self._variables if re.match(r"^x|y", v)]
--> 836         plotter._setup_scales(self, common, layers, coord_vars)
    837 
    838         # Apply statistical transform(s)

/data/anaconda3/shared/xxxxxxxxxx3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core/plot.py in _setup_scales(self, p, common, layers, variables)
   1217 
   1218             prop = PROPERTIES[prop_key]
-> 1219             scale = self._get_scale(p, scale_key, prop, var_df[var])
   1220 
   1221             if scale_key not in p._variables:

/data/anaconda3/shared/xxxxxxxxxx3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core/plot.py in _get_scale(self, spec, var, prop, values)
   1143                 scale = prop.infer_scale(arg, values)
   1144         else:
-> 1145             scale = prop.default_scale(values)
   1146 
   1147         return scale

/data/anaconda3/shared/xxxxxxxxxx3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core/properties.py in default_scale(self, data)
     65         """Given data, initialize appropriate scale class."""
     66 
---> 67         var_type = variable_type(data, boolean_type="boolean", strict_boolean=True)
     68         if var_type == "numeric":
     69             return Continuous()
/data/anaconda3/shared/xxxxxxxxxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core/rules.py in variable_type(vector, boolean_type, strict_boolean)
     95             else:
     96                 boolean_dtypes = ["bool", "boolean"]
---> 97             boolean_vector = vector.dtype in boolean_dtypes
     98         else:
     99             boolean_vector = bool(np.isin(vector, [0, 1, np.nan]).all())
TypeError: data type 'boolean' not understood
```

UPDATE: These are the package versions I am currently using. I will likely ask our environment administrator to update them.

```
Matplotlib version: 3.4.3
Numpy version: 1.20.3
Pandas version: 1.3.3
Statsmodels version: 0.12.2
```

Comment: Code worked just fine for me. Running seaborn 0.12.2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this issue as [not reproducible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWRKH.png). **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

Comment: Maybe it depends on the pandas or numpy version?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, it would not be surprised if you are right. I guess now my question is something closer to "How might I successfully diagnose the error so that I can either fix it on my end or point the package maintainers toward a solution?" Should I modify my question?

Comment: Make sure your packages are updated first. If you’re using anaconda `conda update—all` at the anaconda prompt

Comment: Sadly, I do not maintain the environment. I will try to nudge them to `conda update-all`. You're probably right about needing an update; I have `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `numpy 1.20.3`, and `pandas 1.3.3`. I will mark as a solution unless they discover something crazy.